# jquery how should i search multiple html files for results in realtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

i have this Fiddle Here http://jsfiddle.net/kd6Y4/4/

which is getting div from a different page on same site and display it the problem is its working perfectly online like this direct link http://fiddle.jshell.net/kd6Y4/1/show/ search for hand or and in both

but there is a problem if i am searching a html file which is around 7 mb with more than 6000 div  its hanging for around 20 seconds before giving results and sometime chrome closes when testing   i want to load results from multiple html files at a time and in a way so that results should show instantly and realtime when the searching is being processed   and also it should search multiple html files one after other and display results in chronological order   please help

```
} http://jsfiddle.net/kd6Y4/4/
```

Comment: Consider performing the search on the server

Comment: cant use server search i need to perform search offline in a app from a html file the solution above is working perfectly but is bit slow also i need to search around 10 html files at a time which is around 700 kb each instead of one and results when performing search using above search are coming after around 20 seconds i need a way so that results keep coming in real time so that there will be no waiting period

Answer (score 0):

Javascript follows a single threading computational model. Going through that many divs will block the thread. To avoid this, you can use the parallel computational capabilities of modern processors.

[Parallel.js](http://adambom.github.io/parallel.js/) is one such library that exploits this multi core capabilities of modern browsers.

Say you have 500 divs that needs to be searched.

```
var divs = getDivs();
var worker = new Parallel('search');

worker.spawn(function(divs){
  // do search here
  return result;
}).then(function(result){
  //display the result
});
```

Here we construct a new parallel worker with name 'search', We then spawn a job, passing in an anonymous function. This function receives the divs that needs to be searched, and returns the result.

Finally, call `then` to post/show the returned result.

Parallel depends on the [webworker api](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/), which defines an API for spawning background scripts in your web application. This allows you to fire up long-running scripts to handle computationally intensive tasks, but without blocking the UI or other scripts to handle user interactions.

Comment: i am new to jquery can you please give more light on this answer how can i enable this ?

Comment: You can download parallel.js from [here](https://raw.github.com/adambom/parallel.js/master/lib/parallel.js). load it into your document where the search box is. And when user clicks on search, spawn a worker. Hope it helps. For more details please visit [parallels documentation](http://adambom.github.io/parallel.js/)

Comment: thanks and how should i search multiple html files what changes i need in the code i am using right now can you help in that

Comment: is there any alternative ? I have to use this in a android app